# Calc II Basic differntial equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a homework problem I am unsure of how to do and it's too late to email the professor. We are allowed revisions on homework and it's graded on effort so this is not cheating.

A sphere with radius 1 m has temperature 15°C. It lies inside a concentric sphere with radius 2 m and temperature 25°C. The temperature *T(r)* at a distance *r* from the common center of the spheres satisfies the differential equation:

*d<sup>2</sup>**t*/*dr<sup>2</sup>* + 2/*r* (*dT/dr*) = 0

If we let *S= dT/dr*, then *S* satisfies a first-order differntial equation. Solve it to find an expression for the temperature *T(r)* between the spheres.

So far what I've done is rewrite it as

*SdT/dr* + *(2/r)s* = 0

*S[(dT/dr) + (2/r)]* = 0

I was unsure of what to do from here.

Comment: Thank you, I have added my work. I didn't get very far is why I chose to not include it because I'm essentially stuck at the beginning.

Comment: $\frac{d^2 T}{dr^2}$ means $\frac{d}{dr}(\frac{dT}{dr})$ .

Comment: Your "re-write" is incorrect.  With $S=dT/dr$ you wrote $ S(dT/dr)+(2/ r) S=0$ which is equivalent to $(dT/dr)^2 +(2/r  ). dT/dr=0.$ But generally $(dT/dr)^2\neq d^2T/dr^2.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y=dT/dr.$ Assuming $Y>0$ we have $$(\;dY/dr =-(2 /r) Y\;)\implies (\; Y^{-1}.dY/dx=-2/r\;)\implies$$ $$\implies (\;(d/dr)(\log Y)=-2/r\;)\implies (\;\log Y=K-2 \log r\;)\implies$$ $$\implies (\;dT/dr=Y=e^K/r^2\;)$$ for some constant $K.$ Hence $T=L-e^K/r$ for some constants $L, K$.